# Jquery autosave text area after typing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autosave

I'm trying to learn how to use jQuery, and manipulate some existing code to do what I need it to do. I am wanting to edit this code to make an editable content text area save a certain number of seconds after the user enters information instead of saving on "click".

I have found several different resources on this during my searches, however, none have worked for me with my existing code. Or I may just not be understanding how to combine it with my code. I have tried `.keyup`, `.keypress`, `.ready` and others in my search.

I had one working with an `.on` event, but it created a TON of errors in my site after implementing. -- And now I can't find that code snippet again.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

The current code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {



            $(".save").click(function (e) {

                var mid=$(this).attr('data');

                var tid='#'+mid;

                $(tid).jqte({"status" : false});

            var content = $(tid).html();    

           $(tid).jqte({"status" : true});



            $.ajax({

                dataType:'JSON',

                url: contentedit.ajaxurl,

                type: 'POST',

                data: {

                    action:"contentedit_ajax",

                  content: content,

                  mid:mid

                },              

            });   



  });
```

The portion of the PHP code (with button click saving currently)

```
<div class='abhi_content'><div id='".$putid."' class='abhi_editable' contentEditable='true'>".$edit[0]['editedcontent']."</div><button style='display: none;' id='".$putid."_save' class='save' data='".$putid."'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what is your ID. Let as assume the ID as `example` Here is the code

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#example').on('keyup', function() {
        if(autosave_timer) {
        clearTimeout(autosave_timer);
          }
        autosave_timer = setTimeout(save_by_ajax, 3000); 
// after 3 second of keyup save_by_ajax function will execute
    });

   function save_by_ajax(){
   var mid=$(this).attr('data');

                var tid='#'+mid;

                $(tid).jqte({"status" : false});

            var content = $(tid).html();    

           $(tid).jqte({"status" : true});



            $.ajax({

                dataType:'JSON',

                url: contentedit.ajaxurl,

                type: 'POST',

                data: {

                    action:"contentedit_ajax",

                  content: content,

                  mid:mid

                },              

            });   

    }

});
```

your `$putid` won't be printed as it is not inside php tags. So either give the `ID` manually or print in php correctly.

I'm clearing the function if the user keeps typing without 3 seconds gap. So this avoid server overload. **NO** ajax call be made until the user sits idle for 3 seconds